# Count parts from a tuple list in a key dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary, count, tuples

I have a large dictionary with keys made up with tuple values, like this:

```
Ft = {('Car', 'Blue', 'C1'): 1, ('Bike', 'Red', 'C3'): 10, ('Car', 'Blue', 'C8'): 7, ('Bike', 'Red', 'C12'): 12. ('Car', 'Blue', 'C13'): 5, ('Bus', 'Blue', 'C14'): 17}
```

My goal is to count the amount of the first two values of the tuple keys and setting that into a dictionary for further calculation. Currently this is how I do it:

```
bcc = [] 
for key, value in Ft.iteritems():
    bcc.append((key[0],key[1]))

>>>print bcc 
[('Car', 'Blue'), ('Bike', 'Red'), ('Car', 'Blue'), ('Bike', 'Red'), ('Car', 'Blue'), ('Bus', 'Blue')]
```

Then I will count de values using .count, like this:

```
Count_appearance = {}
for k in list(set(bcc)):
    Count_quays[k] = bcc.count(k)

>>> print Count_appearance
{('Car', 'Blue'): 3, ('Bike', 'Red'): 2, ('Bus', 'Blue'): 1}
```

Since I have to use this a few times over a more bigger dataset, I feel like it is a bit 'spagetti-coding' by first making a list and then count the list.

Is there a easier/quicker way to make the dictionary Count_appearance from Ft?

Comment: Btw, I use [python-2.7]

Comment: `Counter((key[0], key[1]) for key in Ft)`? Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> res = {}
>>> for k, v in Ft.items():
...   if (k[:2]) in res:
...      res[k[:2]] += 1
...   else:
...      res[k[:2]] = 1
... 
>>> res
{('Car', 'Blue'): 3, ('Bus', 'Blue'): 1, ('Bike', 'Red'): 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

Short solution using [***collections.Counter***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) subclass:

```
import collections

Ft = {('Car', 'Blue', 'C1'): 1, ('Bike', 'Red', 'C3'): 10, ('Car', 'Blue', 'C8'): 7, ('Bike', 'Red', 'C12'): 12, ('Car', 'Blue', 'C13'): 5, ('Bus', 'Blue', 'C14'): 17}
counts = dict(collections.Counter(k[:2] for k in Ft))

print counts
```

The output:

```
{('Bike', 'Red'): 2, ('Car', 'Blue'): 3, ('Bus', 'Blue'): 1}
```

Comment: Can you get the output without 'Counter(counts)?